# Fit web page to browser

Tags: css, html, safari

I am having some issues with styling my web page to fit my browser. The width is right but the height only goes about half way down the page. Here is what I have on my CSS: (by the way, I am using safari)

```
/*Body
* {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

body {
font:62.5%/1.5 Arial, Hevetica, sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
background-color: #ccc;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 960%;
}

header {
height: 100px;
background-color: #999;
}

header h1 {
font-size: 2em;
float: left;
}

#nav {
list-style-type: none;
list-style-position: inside;
}

#nav li {
display: inline;
font-size: 2em;
}
```

Comment: Please, provide the html...

Answer (score 1):

you can solve the problem this way

```
html { 
  height: 100%; /* forces page height to equal inner window height. */
  background:gray;
```

}

```
body { 
  position: absolute;
  top:0; 
  bottom:0;
  left:0; 
   right:0;
  background:red;
}
```

also if you don'e need margins for body, so you just need to put margin:0px for body

Comment: Now does this go in my style sheet? and the html part goes in the html file?

Comment: No everything goes to your style.css :)